# Append href begining based on url id

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append the beginning of a list of emails.

this is an example of an email html output :

```
<a id="skypemail" href="username@website.com">test</a>
<a id="skypemail" href="username1@website.com">test</a>
<a id="skypemail" href="username2@website.com">test</a>
<a id="skypemail" href="username@website.com">test</a>
```

And i want it to be :

```
<a id="skypemail" href="sip:username@website.com">test</a>
<a id="skypemail" href="sip:username1@website.com">test</a>
<a id="skypemail" href="sip:username2@website.com">test</a>
<a id="skypemail" href="sip:username@website.com">test</a>
```

Can i do that with JavaScript based on the `id="skypemail"`?

Comment: Did you search it on internet. Where're your attempts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your correctly, you just want to add `sip:` at the beginning of the `href` attr?

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('skypemail');

Array.from(elems).forEach(function(v){
  var elemVal = v.getAttribute('href');
  v.setAttribute('href', 'sip:' + elemVal);
});
```

```html
<a class="skypemail" href="username@website.com">test</a>
<a class="skypemail" href="username1@website.com">test</a>
<a class="skypemail" href="username2@website.com">test</a>
<a class="skypemail" href="username@website.com">test</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for only the first email, except i have many emails, not only one email

Comment: @usethe23 Then provide whole `html` code with other emails (not all, just few of them) and I will edit my answer :)

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear enough. Thank you, i edited my question.

Comment: @usethe23 First of all, remember that `id`'s have to be **unique**. I've changed them into a class. Then just used a `forEach()` function to give each of them the desired `href` attr.

Comment: Thank you, you are right using class is better. It works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit multiple elements use the class attribute. ID is just for unique elements, so change id to class:

```
<a class="skypemail" href="username@website.com">test</a>
<a class="skypemail" href="username1@website.com">test</a>
<a class="skypemail" href="username2@website.com">test</a>
<a class="skypemail" href="username@website.com">test</a>
```

And then, run this javascript code:

```
var emails = document.getElementsByClassName('skypemail');

Array.from(emails).forEach(function(v){
  var elemVal = v.getAttribute('href');
  v.setAttribute('href', 'sip:' + elemVal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify your element you can do something like this:
`const sm = document.querySelector('#skypemail');
sm.href = '<here you can set whatever want for href link>'`